# Dados desencontrados com inner JOIN utilizando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá estou tendo problemas quando estou retornando um select feito com inner join de algumas tabelas conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então montei um inner join com minhas necessidades no meu método:

```
public function tableUsuarioUM() {
    $consulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("SELECT pes.id_pessoa, pes.nome, pes.cpf, end.id_endereco, end.descricao, end.complemento, 
        end.cep,cid.id,cid.nome,cid.id_estado,est.id, est.nome, est.uf, est.id_pais FROM pessoa pes 
        INNER JOIN endereco end ON (pes.id_endereco = end.id_endereco)
        INNER JOIN cidade cid ON (end.id_endereco = cid.id)
        INNER JOIN estado est ON (cid.id = est.id)");
    $consulta->execute();
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $linha->nome. '</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$linha->cpf.'</td>';
                echo ' <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=cadastrarUsuarios&id='.$linha->id_pessoa.'&nome='.$linha->nome.'&id_endereco='.$linha->id_endereco.'&cpf='.
                        $linha->cpf.'">Editar</a>';
                echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-apagar" href="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&id='
                .$linha->id_pessoa.'&nome='.$linha->nome.'&id_endereco='.$linha->id_endereco.'&acao=deletar">Deletar</a></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
    }
}
```

na hora dele trazer os resultados ele está trazendo o nome do Estado ao invés do nome da pessoa, o que pode estar acontecendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: me expressei errado, vou editar tudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua consulta tem vários campos com o mesmo nome em diferentes tabelas, como o php não é fortemente tipado ele pega o último nome e define como a chave do array ou propriedade do objeto

Na consulta abaixo deixei apenas os campos com o mesmo nome para evidenciar a situação:

```
SELECT pes.nome(1), cid.nome(2), est.nome(3) FROM pessoa pes 
        INNER JOIN endereco end ON (pes.id_endereco = end.id_endereco)
        INNER JOIN cidade cid ON (end.id_endereco = cid.id)
        INNER JOIN estado est ON (cid.id = est.id)
```

Para obter os valores certos no php você deve definir um alias para cada campo com o nome igual, isso pode ser feito com a palavra `AS` ou simplesmente definir um novo nome após a coluna.

```
SELECT pes.nome AS p_nome, cid.nome c_nome, est.nome e_nome FROM pessoa pes 
        INNER JOIN endereco end ON (pes.id_endereco = end.id_endereco)
        INNER JOIN cidade cid ON (end.id_endereco = cid.id)
        INNER JOIN estado est ON (cid.id = est.id)
```

Comment: muito boa explicação.

Comment: não funfou, acho que estou escrevendo algo errado

Comment: depois do p_nome não tem virgula?

Comment: Tem sim, ficou faltando uma virgula, obrigado pela observação.

Comment: "SELECT pes.id_pessoa, pes.nome AS p_nome, pes.cpf, end.id_endereco, end.descricao, end.complemento, 
            end.cep,cid.id,cid.nome c_nome,cid.id_estado,est.id, est.nome e_nome, est.uf, est.id_pais FROM pessoa pes 
            INNER JOIN endereco end ON (pes.id_endereco = end.id_endereco)
            INNER JOIN cidade cid ON (end.id_endereco = cid.id)
            INNER JOIN estado est ON (cid.id = est.id)" ainda n funfou

Comment: no mysql funciona mas no php não: SELECT pes.id_pessoa, pes.nome as p_nome, pes.cpf, end.id_endereco, end.descricao, end.complemento, 
            end.cep, cid.id, cid.nome as c_nome, cid.id_estado, est.id, est.nome as e_nome, est.uf, est.id_pais FROM pessoa pes 
            INNER JOIN endereco end ON (pes.id_endereco = end.id_endereco)
            INNER JOIN cidade cid ON (end.id_endereco = cid.id)
            INNER JOIN estado est ON (cid.id = est.id);

Comment: resolvido  o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o @rray demonstrou o que precisava seria as Alias apelidos para algumas colunas de algumas tabelas que são iguais então o método ficou assim:

```
public function tableUsuario() {
    $consulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("SELECT pes.id_pessoa, pes.nome as p_nome, pes.cpf, end.id_endereco, end.descricao, end.complemento, 
        end.cep, cid.id, cid.nome as c_nome, cid.id_estado, est.id, est.nome as e_nome, est.uf, est.id_pais FROM pessoa pes 
        INNER JOIN endereco end ON (pes.id_endereco = end.id_endereco)
        INNER JOIN cidade cid ON (end.id_endereco = cid.id)
        INNER JOIN estado est ON (cid.id = est.id)");
    $consulta->execute();
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $linha->p_nome. '</td>';

                echo '<td>'.$linha->cpf.'</td>';
                echo ' <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=cadastrarUsuarios&id='.$linha->id_pessoa.'&nome='.$linha->p_nome.'&id_endereco='.$linha->id_endereco.'&cpf='.
                        $linha->cpf.'">Editar</a>';
                echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-apagar" href="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerUser&id='
                .$linha->id_pessoa.'&nome='.$linha->p_nome.'&id_endereco='.$linha->id_endereco.'&acao=deletar">Deletar</a></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
    }
}
```

tudo certo.