# Como usar o inner join no php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu estou com o seguinte problema: tenho 2 tabelas e nessas 2 tabelas eu tenho os nomes, sendo que na tabela de curso eu tenho `nome` e na tabela categoria eu também tenho o campo `nome`. Minha dúvida é a seguinte: como que eu faço isso no `PHP`? Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT cur.nome, cat.nome FROM cursos cur INNER JOIN categorias cat ON cur.id_curso = cat.id WHERE cat.id = '$id_categoria'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
```

Após isso, não sei como que eu seleciono tanto o nome do curso quanto o nome da categoria. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Isso nada tem a ver com o php, isso é sql

Comment: Você pode definir um alias para os campos `cur.nome, cat.nome` assim: `cur.nome AS nomeTabelaX, cat.nome AS nomeTabelaY`

Comment: ficaria algo assim? `SELECT cur.nome AS curso, cat.nome AS categoria FROM...`?

Comment: intendi intao obrigado pela resposta

Comment: relacionada também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65624/dados-desencontrados-com-inner-join-utilizando-pdo